# From an select item in the list, create another listbox ZK

Tags: mvvm, listbox, zk

I had a headache with this. I want to choose a book from the 1st list and with that book create a second list to be able to show the details of the book (title, number of pages)

Here is the code:

```
public class Book {

    private int numBook;
    private String nameBook;
    private String author;

    public Book(int numBook, String nameBook, String author) {
        super();
        this.numBook = numBook;
        this.nameBook = nameBook;
        this.author = author;
    }
    public int getNumBook() {
        return numBook;
    }
    public void setNumBook(int numBook) {
        this.numBook = numBook;
    }
    public String getNameBook() {
        return nameBook;
    }
    public void setNameBook(String nameBook) {
        this.nameBook = nameBook;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
```

Class BookData: Load the info in array

```
public class BookData {
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public BookData() {
        loadBooks();
    }
    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }
    public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }
    public void loadBooks() {
        Book b;
        for(int i = 0; i<4;i++){
            b = new Book(i+1, "Libro "+i+1, "Author "+i+1);
            books.add(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Class BookViewModel: ViewModel of Listbox

```
public class BookViewModel {
    private static Book selectedBook;
    private List<Book> booksData = new ArrayList<Book>(new BookData().getBooks()); // Armo los libros

    public List<Book> getBooksData() {
        return booksData;
    }
    public void setBooksData(List<Book> booksData) {
        this.booksData = booksData;
    }
    //Getters and Setter the SelectedCar
    @NotifyChange("selectedBook")
    public Book getSelectedBook() {
        if(selectedBook!=null) {
            //setSelectedBook(selectedBook);
            new DetailData(selectedBook);
            //new ArrayList<>(new DetailData().getDetailsFilterByBook());
            //Then here pass the Book Selected
        }
        return selectedBook;
    }
    public void setSelectedBook(Book selectedBook) {
        this.selectedBook = selectedBook;
    }
}
```

Class Detail: Detail Model of the choose Book

```
public class Detail {
    private int idBook;
    private String title;
    private int numPages;

    public Detail(int idBook, String title, int numPages) {
        this.idBook = idBook;
        this.title = title;
        this.numPages = numPages;
    }
    public int getIdBook() {
        return idBook;
    }
    public void setIdBook(int idBook) {
        this.idBook = idBook;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public int getNumPages() {
        return numPages;
    }
    public void setNumPages(int numPages) {
        this.numPages = numPages;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Detail [idBook=" + idBook + ", title=" + title + ", numPages=" + numPages + "]";
    }
}
```

Class DetailData: Load the data in array

```
//Clase que se ecarga de manejar la data
public class DetailData {
    private List<Detail> details = loadAllDetails();
    private List<Detail> detailsFilterByBook;
    private static Book bookSelected;
    /*public DetailData(){
        //Previously all the data is loaded
        System.out.println(bookSelected);
        detailsFilterByBook = new ArrayList<>();
        filterDetailsByBook();
    }*/
    public void setBookSelected(Book bookSelected){
        this.bookSelected = bookSelected;
    }
    public DetailData(){
        this(bookSelected);
    }
    public DetailData(Book b){
        bookSelected = b;
        System.out.println(bookSelected);
        detailsFilterByBook = new ArrayList<>();
        filterDetailsByBook();      
    }
    public List<Detail> loadAllDetails(){
        List tmp = new ArrayList<Detail>();
        //Libro 1
        Detail d1b1 = new Detail(1, "Preview", 15);
        Detail d2b1 = new Detail(1, "Inicio", 10);
        Detail d3b1 = new Detail(1, "Zk Bind", 50);
        //Libro 2
        Detail d1b2 = new Detail(2, "Introduccion", 15);
        Detail d2b2 = new Detail(2, "JAVA", 100);
        Detail d3b2 = new Detail(2, "CSS", 25);
        //Libro 3
        Detail d1b3 = new Detail(3, "HTML", 35);
        Detail d2b3 = new Detail(3, "Javascript", 40);
        Detail d3b3 = new Detail(3, "Ajax", 25);
        //Libro 4
        Detail d1b4 = new Detail(4, "Android", 100);
        Detail d2b4 = new Detail(4, "IOS", 100);
        tmp.add(d1b1);
        tmp.add(d2b1);
        tmp.add(d3b1);
        tmp.add(d1b2);
        tmp.add(d2b2);
        tmp.add(d3b2);  
        tmp.add(d1b3);
        tmp.add(d2b3);
        tmp.add(d3b3);
        tmp.add(d1b4);
        tmp.add(d2b4);
        return tmp;
    }
    private void filterDetailsByBook() {
        for(Detail d:details){
            if(d.getIdBook() == bookSelected.getNumBook())
                detailsFilterByBook.add(d);
        }
        print();
    }
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Imprimiendo detalles del libro escogido");
        for(Detail d: detailsFilterByBook){
            System.out.println(d);
        }
    }
    public List<Detail> getDetails() {
        return details;
    }
    public void setDetails(List<Detail> details) {
        this.details = details;
    }
    public List<Detail> getDetailsFilterByBook() {
        return detailsFilterByBook;
    }
    public void setDetailsFilterByBook(List<Detail> detailsFilterByBook) {
        this.detailsFilterByBook = detailsFilterByBook;
    }
}
```

Class: DetailViewModel:ViewModel of the second ListBox

```
public class DetailViewModel {
    private List<Detail> detailsData = new ArrayList<>();
    @NotifyChange("detailsData")
    public void refreshList(){
        System.out.println("REFRESH");
        detailsData = new ArrayList<>(new DetailData().getDetailsFilterByBook());
    }
    public List<Detail> getDetailsData() {
        return detailsData;
    }
    @NotifyChange("detailsData")
    public void setDetailsData(List<Detail> detailsData) {
        this.detailsData = detailsData;
    }
}
```

Here is the zul file

```
<window title="" border="none" height="100%" apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewmodel="@id('vm') @init('book.BookViewModel')"> 
    <listbox model="@bind(vm.booksData)" selecteditem="@bind(vm.selectedBook)" emptymessage="No car found in the result"> 
        <listhead> 
            <listheader label="Num Libro"/> 
            <listheader label="Libro"/> 
            <listheader label="Autor"/> 
        </listhead> 
        <template name="model" var="book"> 
            <listitem> 
                <listcell label="@bind(book.numBook)"/> 
                <listcell label="@bind(book.nameBook)"/> 
                <listcell label="@bind(book.author)"/> 
            </listitem> 
        </template> 
    </listbox>
    <separator height="100px"/>
    <window title="" border="none" height="100%" apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
        viewModel="@id('vm') @init('detail.DetailViewModel')">
        <listbox model="@bind(vm.detailsData)" emptyMessage="No existen datos que presentar">
            <listhead>
                <listheader label="Num Capitulos"/>
                <listheader label="Titulo del Cap"/>
            </listhead> 
            <template name="model" var="detail">
                <listitem>
                    <listcell label="@bind(detail.idBook)"/>
                    <listcell label="@bind(detail.title)"/>
                    <listcell label="@bind(detail.numPages)"/>
                </listitem>
            </template>             
        </listbox>
    </window>
</window>
```

I try in the second listbox (At begin have to be empty), show the details of the book everytime when a book in the 1st listbox is selected. I get the correct info. When I choose a book, I get the correct details of that book, but my second listbox does'nt show anything. I will apreciate all the help. PD: Sorry for the english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oke, there are more points to say on this code then you imagine.

### Never use static for a user/session variable.

In your VM you have the following code :

```
private static Book selectedBook;
```

Imagine that I select **Book 1** and you select 2 seconds later **Book 2**.
Because it's static, I'm also having **Book 2** selected, while mine view isn't aware of it.
This means the GUI and server side are out of sync => never a good thing.
If you could be able to sync the view with the selected item, this means that you select **book 2** for me and I'll be searching the number of the Ghost Busters.

### With ZK, always use ListModel interface to give collections to GUI.

While returning `List<Book>` works pretty good, you need to understand the consequences of this action.
A `List` or `Grid` expect an implementation of `ListModel` and if you don't give it, there will be one created every time you notify the list of a change.
While this is a *nice to have feature* it also removes the intelligence of a listmodel and the GUI rendering will be a lot more.
An example is always more clear :

We have a `Collection` of 9 items and we will append 1 to it.

- Adding 1 `Object` to the `List` and notifying it implies that all the content rendered of the `Listbox` will be removed and then adding all the content again to the `Listbox`.
  This means that we are removing and adding 9 lines who aren't changed.
- Adding 1 `Object` to a ListModel, even **without** notifying the ListModel of a change will result in an action where there is only 1 item appended to the `Listbox`.  This is the intelligence of a ListModel => adding and removing items will be persisted to the GUI without overhead.

So your code should be looking like this :

```
private Book selectedBook;
private final ListModelList<Book> booksData = new ListModelList<Book>(new BookData().getBooks()); // Armo los libros
```

### Why not working to the interface and why final?

So I just told you about the interface `ListModel` and yet, I'm setting an implementation of `ListModel` as code, even while we learn to work against interfaces.
The simple reason is that `ListModel` doesn't have methods for appending and removing items while the implementation do have it.
So I make a decision to work against that object in stead of casting it when I need the methods.
Remember, the global getter for the `booksData` can look like this :

```
public ListModel<Book> getBooksData() {
    return booksData;
}
```

So here we hide the implementation of `ListModelList` to the outside.

The reason for `final` is that you will forcing yourself or other people who are going through the code to use the clear() method in stead of making a new `ListModelList`. 
It's just not needed to create a new instance of it.

### Using 2 viewmodel's

Your making yourself difficult of using 2 VM's.
But while it's sometimes a good idea to do this I'll be helping you to get your problem solved.
Your first problem is one of a **naming** kind.

- Viewmodel 1 => called vm in the zul.
- Viewmodel 2 => called vm in the zul.

You see it coming? who will listen when I cry to vm?
let's call the viewmodel of the details `detailVM`

```
viewModel="@id('detailVM') @init('detail.DetailViewModel')"
```

The second problem is that your detail viewmodel doesn't have any clue of the first listbox.
What do I want to say is that your second viewmodel should be holding the correct info of the selected item of the first listbox.

Zul code should be looking like this :

```
<window title="" border="none" height="100%" apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewmodel="@id('vm') @init('book.BookViewModel')">
    <div apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
        viewModel="@id('detailVM') @init('detail.DetailViewModel')">
        <listbox model="@init(vm.booksData)" selecteditem="@bind(detailVM.selectedBook)" emptymessage="No book found in the result"> 
            <listhead> 
                <listheader label="Num Libro"/> 
                <listheader label="Libro"/> 
                <listheader label="Autor"/> 
            </listhead> 
            <template name="model" var="book"> 
                <listitem> 
                    <listcell label="@load(book.numBook)"/> 
                    <listcell label="@load(book.nameBook)"/> 
                    <listcell label="@load(book.author)"/> 
                </listitem> 
            </template> 
        </listbox>
    <separator height="100px"/>

        <listbox model="@init(detailVM.detailsData)" emptyMessage="No existen datos que presentar">
            <listhead>
                <listheader label="Num Capitulos"/>
                <listheader label="Titulo del Cap"/>
            </listhead> 
            <template name="model" var="detail">
                <listitem>
                    <listcell label="@load(detail.idBook)"/>
                    <listcell label="@load(detail.title)"/>
                    <listcell label="@load(detail.numPages)"/>
                </listitem>
            </template>             
        </listbox>
    </div>
</window>
```

So I set you up with the correct zul, and now it's up to you to modify the viewmodels.
Remember that I set selectedBook in detailVM so now it's not needed in the first viewmodel.
**I don't write everything for you, otherwise you wouldn't learn from it.**

### Some small things left to say.

You see I change the listbox model to `@init` and not `@bind`.
A model is always read only, so please NEVER NEVER NEVER use `@bind`.
`@load` is the highest annotation you could use, and this is only the case when you will create a new instance for the `ListModel`, witch is hardly needed.

Labels, are also not updatable in your GUI.
Again `@bind` is over the top, `@load` should be used in normal situations (when the value can change, so most commonly) or `@init` when the value will never change, but if you use `@load` I'll be happy already.

Hope this could set you to the right direction.
If you have any other question, just comment below.

Comment: Thanks to take your time to give me a guide, I'm new in ZK. I'll follow your advice. Cheers

Comment: We can see that your learning, example of book case is every where known :). I see that you did look (and copy) some parts of the car example.
Don't worry, with good tips and tricks you get there.